# Sum of sparse vectors: bug or feature?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, array-broadcasting

I recently stumbled upon the following behavior in MATLAB R2022a:

```
>> a = sparse(1,2,1)
a =
   (1,2)        1

>> b = sparse(2,1,18)
b =
   (2,1)       18

>> a+b
ans =
   (2,1)       18
   (1,2)        1
   (2,2)       19
```

The presence of the (2,2) element with value 19 is quite puzzling. Intuitively, I would have expected to get either a zero (no element) or an error indicating that the vectors' sizes are not compatible. I couldn't find an explanation for this behavior in the documentation.

So, is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to implicit broadcasting and expected behaviour, also for `full()` arrays. Compare:

```
bsxfun(@plus, [0 1], [0; 18])

ans =

     0     1
    18    19
```

(I'm running R2007b, so need `bsxfun()` instead of implicit broadcasting).

What happens with unequal-sized vectors is that they are broadcast ("extended") into the appropriate size for addition, see [e.g. this blog post](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) on an in-depth explanation.

Verbosely writing our toy example

```
a = [0 1]
b = [ 0
     18]

a + b = [0 1] + [ 0
                 18]

      % Is broadcast to
      = [0 1     [ 0  0
         0 1] +   18 18]

      % element wise addition
      =  [ 0  1
          18 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact similarly happening with full arrays, *i.e.* not restricted to sparse vectors, and this is normal behavior according to the [documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html) (see the **Add Row and Column Vector** section).